# Jhipster Gatway app logs show "Config Server: Not found or not setup for this application"

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

This issue should have been fixed long back as per this 
[Github ticket](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3166)
Why Am i still seeing this in logs.

```
Config Server:  Not found or not setup for this application

2017-10-30 15:03:53.740  INFO 24700 --- [           main] foo.bar.id.gateway.GatewayApp         : 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'Gateway' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8180
    External:   http://ipadddress:8180
    Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-30 15:03:53.740  INFO 24700 --- [           main] foo.bar.id.gateway.GatewayApp         : 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Config Server:  Not found or not setup for this application
----------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-30 15:03:55.310  INFO 24700 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_AppGATEWAY/Gateway:2c4703cd1cbf3617def055e786113743: registering service...
2017-10-30 15:03:55.328  INFO 24700 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_AppGATEWAY/Gateway:2c4703cd1cbf3617def055e786113743 - registration status: 204
2017-10-30 15:08:20.870  INFO 24700 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration


  [1]: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3166
```

Comment: Did you start the jhipster-registry project before starting your gateway?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

If you expect that the config server may occasionally be unavailable when your application starts, you can make it keep trying after a failure. First, you need to set spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true. Then you need to add spring-retry and spring-boot-starter-aop to your classpath. The default behavior is to retry six times with an initial backoff interval of 1000ms and an exponential multiplier of 1.1 for subsequent backoffs. You can configure these properties (and others) by setting the spring.cloud.config.retry.* configuration properties.

Docs:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#config-client-retry

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following properties in your GitHub configuration repo.

```
configserver:
    name: JHipster Registry config server
    status: Connected to the JHipster Registry config server, using https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry-sample-config !
```